# Deploying an application in lower verison of tomcat - throws errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a maven based web application which I deployed in Tomcat-(V 7.0.59) and it's working fine without any issue, Now I had to deploy the same .war file in different tomcat-(V 6.0.16) and it's throwing some errors. And I guess this is because of the jars, When I change the  in maven to 6.0.16 it's showing errors like:

```
- Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-
 embed-el:jar:6.0.16
- Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-
 embed-core:jar:6.0.16
- Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:
 6.0.16
- Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-
 embed-websocket:jar:6.0.16
```

I also checked for these jars in maven repo but I din't find any of these, Did anyone come across the same issue? Or can anyone suggest me on how to solve this and deploy the application in tomcat-(V 6.0.16).

Comment: In Maven Central only 7.0.0 and above but not 6.X ...What you might try is to download Tomcat 6.0.16 from Apache are and upload the appropriate jar's into your own repository manager... https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/

Comment: Do you really need Tomcat 6.0.16 ? 9 year old version?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the quick response, Yes, actually the project I'm working on is completely deployed in the older version of tomcat and they can't upgrade now, So I had to deploy my webapp in the same tomcat. I'll try doing what you suggested, Do you have any others suggestions?

Comment: I was also searching for these jars online --> **embed-el, embed-core, embed-websocket, tomcat-jdbc:jar** for tomcat 6.0.16 but din't find any, Any other suggestions please?

Comment: As far as I know in older versions things like embed-core didn't exists...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the response, End of the day I din't find those and had to do it in a different server.